# count number of a specific string on consecutive lines

Tags: bash, shell, tcl, sh

I'm rather new to Linux and would like to use a shell script to count the number of times a specific string appears in concurrent lines of text.

For example, I have a log with data similar to this:

```
 active node table^M
 -------------------^M
     pkey  vlan  master-s/n  gateway-s/n  gateway-prio      if-name        gateway name   advertised ip
   0x7fff     0         N/A      0xa0600           100          if0      DA2WIBL1-25-io   10.126.144.49
   0x7fff     0         N/A      0xa0580           100          if0      DA2WIBL1-31-io   10.126.144.51
   0x7fff     0         N/A      0xa0400           100          if0      DA2WIBL1-28-io   10.126.144.50
 active node table
 -------------------
```

I want to simply count the number of concurrent lines containing the string: `'0x7fff'`, and write that to a file.

Does anyone have an idea of how to wisely approach this? I know some shell, expect and similar scripting languages.

Comment: What do you mean by "concurrent lines"?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean "In the lines between 'active node table' headers, how many times does 0x7fff appear" -- is that right?

Comment: You all are correct, I sincerely apologize for not being clear enough. I was looking for concurrent lines containing the pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "consecutive" by "concurrent", then you normally use `uniq` command to group consecutive lines, `uniq -c` to group and count them simultaneously:

```
cat logfile | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -c | grep '0x7fff' | awk '{print $1}'
```

Given content of logfile as:

```
0x7fff     0         N/A      0xa0600           100          if0      DA2WIBL1-25-io   10.126.144.49
0x7fff     0         N/A      0xa0580           100          if0      DA2WIBL1-31-io   10.126.144.51
0x7fff     0         N/A      0xa0400           100          if0      DA2WIBL1-28-io   10.126.144.50
0x8b5f     0         N/A      0xa0600           100          if0      DA2WIBL1-25-io   10.126.144.49
0x7fff     0         N/A      0xa0400           100          if0      DA2WIBL1-28-io   10.126.144.50
```

, above command will produce the following output:

```
3
1
```

Comment: Well this definitely is a candidate for the [*useless use of cat*](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)...

Answer (score 0):

`grep "0x7fff" logfilename.log | wc -l`

the above code could help finding the count of number of lines in which the pattern or the string valye "0x7fff" appears.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I may not have initially clarified enough that I need to count consecutive lines containing the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v key='0x7fff' '{if($1==key) c++; else {print c; c=0}} 
                   END {print c}' file
```

test using @gudok's sample with

```
3
1
```